# Автотесты с помощью python selenium в java spring application

Tags: python, java, selenium, юнит-тесты

Нормальная ли это практика в проекте Java Spring тестировать сайт с помощью Python Selenium? Пока из минусов всплывает, насколько я знаю, только отсутствие совместимости с maven, gradle и прочими сборщиками;  пониженная скорость из-за особенностей языка Python; отсутствие возможности указать аннотацией SpringBootTest, Test. А из больших преимуществ: скорость написания скриптов для тестирования из-за простоты языка, хорошей «дружбы» Python’a с Selenium и заточенности языка под написание макросов.